# Duvida em um exercício de Java

Tags: java, junit

Eu estava procurando uns exercícios de Java para treinar e aprender alguns algoritmos quando me deparei com o site **exercism.io** e resolvi fazer os exercícios deles de Java. Até aí tudo certo, baixei o app deles usando o [chocolately](https://chocolatey.org/) e instalei o [gradle](http://gradle.org/) pra rodar os testes. Achei a proposta metodológica de exercícios deles muito interessante até que veio o problema.

O problema é o seguinte:

Quando você faz a requisição de exercício pelo cmd usando o comando:

```
$ exercism fetch java hello-world
```

O exercício já vem com bugs (intencionalmente) para que você os ache e resolva todos. Depois de resolvidos os bugs, e rodando o comando:

```
$ gradle test
```

dentro da pasta do exercício, tudo deveria correr bem e então você está liberado para submeter sua resposta usando o comando:

```
$ exercism submit src/main/java/HelloWorld.java
```

indicando o caminho do seu código na submissão:

Agora que vem o problema.

O seguinte código é usado para testes:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class HelloWorldTest {

    @Test
    public void helloNoName() {
        assertEquals("Hello, World!", HelloWorld.hello(""));
        assertEquals("Hello, World!", HelloWorld.hello(null));
    }

    @Test
    public void helloSampleName() {
        assertEquals("Hello, Alice!", HelloWorld.hello("Alice"));
    }

    @Test
    public void helloAnotherSampleName() {
        assertEquals("Hello, Bob!", HelloWorld.hello("Bob"));
    }
}
```

O que eu entendi que esse código deveria fazer é receber uma string do programa principal e testar se caso a string for vazia do tipo `""` ou `void` ele deveria retornar: **Hello, World!**.

Caso seja escrito no programa principal o nome Alice ou Bob ele retornaria ou **Hello, Alice!** ou **Hello, Bob!**

O meu programa principal está da seguinte maneira:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static String hello(String name) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Eu já tentei colocar as três strings válidas concatenadas, três retornos no método, montei um array de strings e mandei exibir um de cada vez e nada.

O problema é que o requisito do exercício pede que isso seja resolvido editando o programa principal que é o **HelloWorld.java** isso me impede de alterar o programa de teste que é o **HelloWorldTest.java** pois isso seria trapacear.

O erro que o `gradle` me exibe é esse aqui:

```
PS C:\Users\anton\exercism\java\hello-world> gradle test
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test

HelloWorldTest > helloAnotherSampleName FAILED
    org.junit.ComparisonFailure at HelloWorldTest.java:20

HelloWorldTest > helloSampleName FAILED
    org.junit.ComparisonFailure at HelloWorldTest.java:15

HelloWorldTest > helloNoName FAILED
    org.junit.ComparisonFailure at HelloWorldTest.java:9

3 tests completed, 3 failed
:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/Users/anton/exercism/java/hello-world/build/reports/tests/inde
x.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.581 secs
```

Se alguém souber como eu resolvo isso me manda uma dica aqui.

Comment: Pelo que entendi do Teste, o método `hello()` recebe uma string e concatena com o "Hello, ", caso a string seja nula ou vazia, exibe "Hello, word!". Isso já responde sua pergunta, agora mãos a obra! :D

Comment: Eu até responderia com o método pronto, mas acho que será mais construtivo pra você mesmo essa criação.

Comment: Vou continuar tentando aqui, espero conseguir logo

Comment: Eu já te dei praticamente um "portugol", basta transformar isso em código.

Comment: O HelloWord da pergunta não atende aos testes unitarios apresentados. Edite a pergunta e adiciona seu programa principal desse teste ai.

Comment: Eu só troquei pra return name;

Comment: Ainda não atende, você não tá checando se a string name é vazia ou nula, e não está concatenando com **Hello,**

Comment: Conseguiiiiiiii, Vlw Diegão =)

Comment: Disponha! :D Podes responder sua propria pergunta com o código.

Comment: Não entendi porque que questão foi fechada por "fora do escopo", mesmo se tratando de programação, e possuindo um exemplo reproduzível do problema e a tentativa de resolução, apesar de se tratar de um exercício.

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo [discutida no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4772/pergunta-fechada-como-fora-do-escopo-mesmo-sendo-sobre-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você já postou uma solução, mas essa solução não é bem a que eu estava te direcionando nos comentários, então vou te explicar melhor como poderia ter feito.

Partindo dos métodos de testes, estes te dão algumas dicas a respeito do funcionamento do método `hello()`, como este método de teste:

```
@Test
    public void helloNoName() {
        assertEquals("Hello, World!", HelloWorld.hello(""));
        assertEquals("Hello, World!", HelloWorld.hello(null));
    }
```

Os testes acima mostram que, caso seja passada uma `String` vazia ou um valor nulo para o método `hello()`, ele deve retornar *`Hello, World!`*.

Nos métodos seguinte:

```
@Test
public void helloSampleName() {
    assertEquals("Hello, Alice!", HelloWorld.hello("Alice"));
}

@Test
public void helloAnotherSampleName() {
    assertEquals("Hello, Bob!", HelloWorld.hello("Bob"));
}
```

O teste mostra que, ao se passar a `String` *Alice* como parâmetro, esperasse que seja exibido *Hello, Alice!*, no seguinte o teste é o mesmo, só que passando o nome *`Bob`*.

Após observar o funcionamento dos testes, já podemos montar o possível método `hello()`, e uma de suas formas poderia ser a seguinte:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static String hello(String name) {
        if(name != null && !name.isEmpty()){
            return "Hello, " + name;  
        } else {
            return "Hello, World!";
        }
    }
}
```

O código acima atenderia ao seu problema sem ficar dependente de qual `String` for passada, mas claro, baseando-se apenas no que foi apresentado nos testes. Há outras formas de se fazer este método, mas acredito que essa forma seja uma das mais simples.

Obs.: O método `isEmpty()` só está disponível a partir do Java SE 6.

**Referências:**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()

[Java, check whether a string is not null and not empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3598792/5524514)

Comment: Valeu pela explicação Diego, eu to tentando fazer esse mesmo exercício usando ternário nesse exato momento, mais ta meio bugado. Quanto mais maneira de se resolver um problema melhor então obrigado por mais essa resolução.

Answer (score 2):

Bom gente graças ao usuário [Diego Felipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/28595/diego-felipe) eu consegui resolver essa dúvida então estou postando a resposta aqui:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static String hello(String name) {
        if((name=="") || (name==null)){
            name = "Hello, World!";
        } else {
            if(name=="Alice"){
                name = "Hello, Alice!";
            } else {
                if(name=="Bob"){
                    name = "Hello, Bob!";
                }
            }
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```

Eu não estava entendendo os requisitos, era só fazer uma verificação conforme me explicou o Diego. Vlw Diego.